# Torsors and twists of algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, tannakian-category

Let $G/S$ be an affine group scheme. Then the automorphism group of every $G$-torsor over $S$ is a twist of $G$, but it  this functor isn't essentially surjective in general (It may be not full nor faithful as well). Does there exists a good criterion which determines twists of $G$ that are the automorphism group of a $G$-torsor over $S$? I'm also interested in explicit special cases if there is no general solution.

---

As I think, (at least in the case $S= \mathrm{Spec}(k)$) by the theory of Tannakian categories, the category of fiber functors$/S$ of the tensor category of finite representations of $G$ is equivalent to the category of $G$-torsors. On the other hand every neutral Tannakian category is isomorphic to the category of finite representations of the automorphism group of it's fiber functor. So by these facts one can conclude that two affine group schemes have isomorphic tensor categories of representations if one is the automorphism group of a torsor over the other. This is the reason why I'm interested in the above problem. Please let me know if there are flaws in these arguments. Thanks!

Comment: A necessary condition: the automorphism group of a $G$-torsor is always an inner form of $G$

Comment: It's also sufficient: if you take a neutral Tannakian category, then the algebraic groups that arise as the tensor automorphism group of a fiber functor are exactly the inner forms of one of them. This is easy to work out using that two fiber functors become isomorphic over some extension of k.

Comment: Hmm--it seems to me that the map sending a $G$-torsor to the associated inner form of $G$ is just the natural map $H^1(S, G)\to H^1(S, G/Z_G)$ induced by the map $G\to G/Z_G$ (here we view $G/Z_G$ as the group of inner automorphisms of $G$).  So it seems to me that the surjectivity is governed by $H^2(S, Z_G)$; I see no reason for this to be zero in general.

Comment: I am not sure the terminology is completely fixed, but in my view, a "form" of $G$ (equivalently, a class in $H^1(S,\mathrm{Aut}\,(G))$) is called "inner" if it is in the image of $H^1(S,\mathrm{Int}\,(G))$, and is a "strong inner form"  if it is in the image of $H^1(S,G)\to H^1(S,\mathrm{Int}\,(G))\to H^1(S,\mathrm{Aut}\,(G))$. As Daniel Litt observes, none of these maps has any reason to be injective or surjective in general.  The (classes of) automorphism groups of $G$-torsors are the *strong* inner forms.

Comment: @anon, thanks! I have another related question: Is the automorphism group of an affine group scheme always affine? And in the case of algebraic groups, algebraic?

Comment: @Mostafa,  Regarding your new question, "Is the automorphism group ... always affine?", the answer is "no".  For $G=\mathbb{G}_m\times \mathbb{G}_m$, the automorphism group has countably many connected components via the action of $\mathbf{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ on $G$.  So it makes sense to restrict to the connected component of the identity.

Comment: To complement Jason's example, at least the automorphism sheaf of $\mathbb{G}_m\times\mathbb{G}_m$ is a scheme, namely the constant group scheme $\underline{SL(2,\mathbb{Z})}$. The automorphism sheaf of $\mathbb{G}_a$ is not even a scheme.

Comment: @Laurent $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{G}_a)=\mathbb{G}_m$?

Comment: @Mostafa: sorry, $\mathbb{G}_a$ was too simple. But take $G:=\mathbb{G}_a\times\mathbb{G}_m$: over $\mathbb{Q}[t]/(t^{n+1})$ we have an automorphism of $G$ sending $(x,u)$ to $(x,u\exp(tx))$. These are compatible for varying $n$, but do not "glue" to give an automorphism over $\mathbb{Q}[[t]]$.

Comment: @Mostafa: on second thought, we only have  $\underline{\mathrm{Aut}}(\mathbb{G}_{a,\mathbb{Q}})=\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{Q}}$. If $S$ has characteristic $p>0$ and $t\in\mathscr{O}_S$, then $x\mapsto x+tx^p$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{G}_{a,S}$ iff $t$ is locally nilpotent. Thus we have a compatible family of automorphisms over $\mathbb{F}_p[t]/(t^{n+1})$ that does not extend to $\mathbb{F}_p[[t]]$.

Comment: @Laurent So does there exists a good description of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{G}_{a,\mathbb{Z}})$ ?